# Octokit pagination does not play well with Typescript

Tags: typescript, octokit-js

I have the following reasonably straight-forward code:

```js
export async function getAllRepos({
  token,
}: {
  token: string;
}): Promise<ReposListForOrgResponseData> {
  const octokit = buildOctokit(token);

  const repos = await octokit.paginate(octokit.repos.listForOrg, {
    org: OWNER,
  });

  return repos;
}
```

Typescript does not like this and gives me the error:

```
src/lib/github.ts:130:3 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; node_id: string; name: string; full_name: string; owner: { name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; login: string; id: number; node_id: string; avatar_url: string; ... 14 more ...; starred_at?: string | undefined; }; ... 79 more ...; allow_forking?: boolean | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ReposListForOrgResponseData'.
  Type '{ id: number; node_id: string; name: string; full_name: string; owner: { name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; login: string; id: number; node_id: string; avatar_url: string; ... 14 more ...; starred_at?: string | undefined; }; ... 79 more ...; allow_forking?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; node_id: string; name: string; full_name: string; owner: { login: string; id: number; node_id: string; avatar_url: string; gravatar_id: string; url: string; html_url: string; followers_url: string; ... 9 more ...; site_admin: boolean; }; ... 73 more ...; license: { ...; }; }'.
    The types of 'owner.gravatar_id' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

130   return repos;
      ~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure why the types don't match up but it's impossible to figure this out following the definitions or looking at the octokit website. `@octokit/rest` and `@octokit/types` don't seem to have anything to do with each other.

Octokit/rest is at 18.12.0 and the types are at 5.5.0.

Comment: What is the definition of `ReposListForOrgResponseData`? Where does it come from? I can't find anything on the internet other than your question referencing that.

Comment: Looking at the package-lock.json file on the 18.x branch (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/rest.js/18.x/package-lock.json) I can see that all it's dependencies require @oktokit/types ^6.x, which means you are using an incompatible version. That's where the type mismatch is probably coming from.

Comment: I too had a hard time finding it in the code but it seems it's provided by the octokit types.

Answer (score 1):

The same is happening to me, I'm not TS expert but for now, I am dealing with it using Type Assertion:

```js
import { Endpoints } from '@octokit/types'

let repos: unknow = octokit.paginate(octokit.rest.apps.listReposAccessibleToInstallation, {...})
    
repos = repos as Endpoints['GET /installation/repositories']['response']['data']['repositories']
```